# is Debut of an optional set a stopping time? (under no usual hypothesis)

Tags: stochastic-analysis

Do not assume usual hypothesis. Let $A$ be a set measurable with respect to optional sigma-algebra.
Then is debut of $A$, $D_A$, a stopping time with respect to $F$ or $F_+$ filtration?

I know that if filtration is complete then the debut of a progressive set is a $(F)$ stopping time. But in case of not necesseraliy complete filtration, by assuming stronger condition of optionality, I feel that may give the same result.